# how to prepend content in span onChange value of input box

Tags: jquery, prepend

I have an input box

and I have a span tag that contains some text:
Waiting for user action..

What I am trying to do is, when the value of the inputbox changes I want it to add(prepend) the value in the span tag in a new line.

So if I keep adding lets say: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7,something,or

then the span has

```
or
something
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
Waiting for user action..
```

Anyone please help?

Thanks 
Praney

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert but this may help a little.

```
<input type="text" id="myBox">
<span id="mySpan">Waiting for user action</span>
```

And a bit of jQuery to update the SPAN.

```
$("#myBox").keyup(function() {
    var myBoxContents = $("#myBox").val();
    var mySpanContents = $("#mySpan").text();
    $("#mySpan").html(myBoxContents+"<br>"+mySpanContents);
});
```

Comment: I've just realised this may not work as it should. This will produce a <BR> tag for every letter typed, meaning if you typed "something", it would return s<br>o<br>m<br>e<br>t..... I'll try and edit it for you so it gets the right result

Comment: @praneybehl: Are you entering the commas in the text box like your question shows, 1,2,3,4,something... or will the words be split by whitespaces?

Comment: Actually @praneybehl I have to disappear quickly. See TehBeardMan's answer, he has it spot on.

Comment: sorry I lost power here, I am changing the value of the input box through an internal function. It would not be with commas, just individual strings.

Comment: The problem is that myBoxContents will return the full text within the textbox, not just the last character typed.  so youll end up with 7654321 <br> 654321 <br> 54321 <br>... etc

Comment: @Will P: Yes, I realised I got it wrong, and I was going to fix it, but nobody really knows what the guy wants, so I'm not going to bother. I thought TehBeardMan had the answer spot on, his demo works fine, but the guy said it was wrong - so who knows what he wants...

Comment: @Will thats correct but I figured it out, from the 2nd answer also that was outputting text so I changed it to html s i can actually get a line break.
Thanks all for the help though. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
$('#textbox_id').keyup(function(e){
    $('#span_id').prepend(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) + '<br>');
});
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

**Updated code to show output desired in update question**

I would put the span in front of your text and simply update that span with what the user has input

html:

```
<input type="text" id="text_input"><br>
<span id="userInput"></span>Waiting for user action
```

jquery:

```
$("#text_input").keyup(function() {
    var data = $("#text_input").val();
    var myarray = data.split(",");
    var output = $("<span />");
    for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        myarray[i] != "" ? output.prepend(myarray[i] + "<br>") : "" ;   
    }
    $("#userInput").html(output.html());
});
```

working example http://jsfiddle.net/64FVx/6/

Comment: ah the question requirements changed some while I was working on my answer. Give me a minute and I'll modify what I posted to make it output how you have it now.

Comment: thanks for the reply mate but this just changes the next up position span.